# Network Usage of Process Using Powershell

Tags: performance, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to calculate the bytes sent and recieved by a particular process .I want to use powershell for that.
Something which I can do using Resource Monitor->Network Activity.
How can i do that using get-counter?

Comment: Try looking at the `Get-Counter` cmdlet

Comment: As others have noted (years ago), it's hard to do.  AFAICT, it still is.  But if you settle for the suggestion of measuring total network traffic (not process-specific), then you could run  netstat -s -p IP -e and parse its output. The following regex captures total bytes received, total bytes sent, and packages received on IPv4 (assuming today's output of that netstat command): ".*?Bytes\s*(\d*)\s*(\d*).*?IPv4 Statistics.*?Packets Received.*?\= (\d*)"

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good Scripting Guy article on using the `Get-Counter` cmdlet here:

[Scripting Guy - Get-Counter](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/31/use-powershell-to-simplify-collecting-performance-information.aspx)

The trick will be finding the counter that you need, and I don't think you can get the granularity you're after as these are the same counters that PerfMon uses.  It's more focused around the whole Network Interface than it is around the individual processes using the interface.  With that said, if it's the only thing using the given interface it should do the trick nicely.

Have a look at the Network Interface options available for a start:

```
(get-counter -list "Network Interface").paths
```

Comment: The link is a victim of link rot. Here is the recent link. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/gathering-network-statistics-with-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it seems. I'm absolutely unable to find the counters the performance monitor is reading from, though other people may chime in. There may be some other way than get-counter too, but that is what you specifically requested.

Looking through the counters, the closest thing you will find is the "IO Read Bytes/sec" and "IO Write Bytes/sec" counters on the process object.

The problem with those is that they count more than just network activity. The description in perfmon says:

> "This counter counts all I/O activity generated by the process to
>   include file, network and device I/Os."

That being said, if you know that the process you want to monitor only or mainly writes to the network connection, this may be better than not measuring anything at all.

You'd go about it like this (I'll use Chrome as an example since it is conveniently running and using data right now):

```
get-counter "\Process(chrome*)\IO Read Bytes/sec"
```

This will just give you a one-time reading. If you want to keep reading you can add the continous switch.

The PerformanceCounterSampleSet object that is returned is not exactly pretty to work with, but you can find the actual reading in $obj.countersamples.cookedvalue.

The list will be fairly long (if you browse like me). Chrome is running in many separate processes, so we'll do a bit of math to get them all added up, and presented in KB.

Final result:

```
get-counter "\Process(chrome*)\IO Read Bytes/sec" -Continuous | foreach {
    [math]::round((($_.countersamples.cookedvalue | measure -sum).sum / 1KB), 2)
    }
```

Running this will just continously output a reading of how many KB/s Chrome is using.

Comment: Seems like this does not work for a Nagios client C:\Program Files\NSClient++\nscp.exe. Process Explorer shows Network I/O received bytes, but all of those I/O counters in perfmon remain 0...

Comment: @McVitas above code is IO Read, which includes Disk-IO. So, numbers differ from Network-IO shown in perfmon.